# Spring security - is it possible to use @EnableOAuth2Sso, @EnableResourceServer and @EnableAuthorizationServer on the same application?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I am busy setting up an oauth2 authentication server. Currently i have the authentication server and the resource server within one application. I am curious though if is possible to also setup a client within the application. I added the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation but am getting an error

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoRestTemplateFactory' available
```

Hence my question if it is possible to use @EnableOAuth2Sso, @EnableResourceServer and @EnableAuthorizationServer on the same application.

Also i would appreciate an explanation as to why it isn't possible.